# Showing image title with imshow method in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, plot, title, imshow

How can I show image titles in MATLAB figures?  I have the following code below:

```
I=imread('./../images/pap.png');
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(I); % here I want to show labels
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`title`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html) command.  It works pretty much like `plot`.  `imshow` spawns a new figure so you can apply commands that you would for any figure in here.  By using `title`, you will give your image a title and it appears at the top of your image.

As such:

```
I=imread('./../images/pap.png');
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(I);
title('Labels'); % Place title here
```